# CoronaSDK timer.performWithDelay iteration confusion

Tags: android, timer, lua, coronasdk

Good day. I'm a newbie in CoronaSDk and I am facing a problem regarding to timer.performWithDelay. Here's my code:

```
local time
function main()
    display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
    time = 180
    timelimiter()
    timelimit = timer.performWithDelay(1000,decreaseTime,0)
end

function timelimiter()
    timeNumber = display.newGroup()
    timeNumber = display.newText("Time: "..tostring(time), 1, 0, native.systemFontBold, 14)
    timeNumber.x = 330
    timeNumber.y = 300
end

function decreaseTime()
    time = time - 1
    timeNumber.isVisible = false
    timelimiter()
    print(time)
    if(tostring(time) == "0") then
    print("Finish!")
    timer.pause(timelimit)
    end

end
main()
```

This code run as expected. I even tried to create a new main.lua file with these codes and I was able to run it without errors. But my problem is when I implemented it to a game I was trying to make, the loop stops at 176. Can anyone help me with this? The whole code of my project is here (the specific lua file I was referring to).

http://pastebin.com/98CR6mnW

Thank you for your help. Sorry for my english though. :)

Comment: Probably not related but why do you set `timeNumber.isVisible=false`, which will hide it, then you never make it visible again? Also, you rarely need `tostring`, Lua does htis for you, so in `display.newText` no need, and in `decreaseTime` use `if time == 0 then`.

Comment: I set the timeNumber.isVisible=false preceeded by timelimiter() so that it wont overlap the current text displayed. Thanks for your quick response btw. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure yet what is causing this but you are creating a timer text at every second, that is not necessary. In principle they should be in order so you likely see latest but it is a bit odd. So first need to clean up code: if I understand what you are trying to do, try this:

```
function timelimiter()
    timeNumber.setText("Time: "..time)
    timeNumber.x = 330
    timeNumber.y = 300
end
```

and create timeNumber in main():

```
function main()
    timeNumber = display.newGroup()
    timeNumber = display.newText("Time: "..time, 1, 0, native.systemFontBold, 14)
    display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
    time = 180
    timelimiter()
    timelimit = timer.performWithDelay(1000, decreaseTime, 0)
end
```

Then your decreaseTime would be something like

```
function decreaseTime()
    time = time - 1
    -- timeNumber.isVisible = false
    timelimiter()
    print(time)
    if time  == 0 then
        print("Finish!")
        timer.pause(timelimit)
    end
end
```

Once you've tried this update your post based on new data you have.

Comment: Okay! Thank you! When I got home, I'll try this. I'll update you soon.Thank you for your quick response! :)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! Your solution greatly helped me. I finally fixed it. Thanks!